# Apache ECharts multiple Y axis

Tags: angular, typescript, apache-echarts

I'm trying to use the Echarts library, and I need to draw a graph with different units of measurement on the Y axis. I've found two things I can't fix:

1. How do I adapt the Y-axis distance based on the maximum value automatically? I'm using the offset parameter inside the "yAxis" object. Is there a way to make it adjust the distance based on the data contained in the Y-axis? I used this link as an example:

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=multiple-y-axis

2. Another problem that I can't solve is that when I actually hide one or more variables (as seen in the example link hiding example "evaporation" in the Y axis is only hidden but not "collapsed" this way I get busy with some empty space (e.g. if I hide the "middle" variable to the others) is there a way to fix this so that they re-fit next to each other when I hide them? thanks
   [image: In yellow the space when i hide a variable]

[image: In yellow the space when i hide a variable]

In yellow the space when i hide a variable